# Imagemagick generates b&w image while rendering coloured text in an SVG image

Tags: svg, imagemagick

This command

```
convert \
    -density 300 \
    -gravity west \
    pango:'<span font="ubuntu 20" foreground="red" background="white">text1\n</span><span font="ubuntu 12" foreground="red" background="#3fa">text2</span>' \
    -gravity center \
    -extent 700x800 \
    caption.svg
```

creates a b&w image (text in black, all background in white), no colors in it.
The same command with `caption.png` works fine.

Update: this is the [image code](https://pastebin.com/9NQZzZiz).

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be reporting this [here](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues)?

Comment: @RobertLongson I thought I was missing something in my command...

Comment: If that's the case it's not a programming problem and therefore isn't on-topic here.

Comment: Post your svg image. I think you may have some syntax issues.  Set the density, then read the SVG file, then apply gravity, text and extent after reading the SVG file.  What is your Imagemagick version?  What do you get for Delegates when you do `convert -version`.  What version of Pango?

Comment: If the SVG is styled using CSS, that could explain why all (?) elements are black.

Comment: @fmw42 yep, updated...

Comment: @fmw42 couldn't find the way to check `pangocairo` version

Comment: @nightcod3r Post a link to your SVG file.

Comment: @fmw42 it's been updated in the question...

Comment: I get an abort trap 6 related to an Inkscape error when I try to convert your svg to png.  Although I get an error, a file is created, but it is black and white.  This is likely due to the Inkscape error.  You may have something in your file that is incompatible with Inkscape.